# How To Stop Animation/GIF And Display A Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a simple animation made in Flash which is colour changing wheel wheel, and GIF ready too. When somebody goes to my site, the wheel keeps animating.

But what I need is that when someone presses the "Stop Animation" button near the animation, a message to be displayed on the screen. It would be better if it can be popped out and can be sent to the user's email id he inputs.

A great thanks from my side to someone who can help me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CreateJS export from Anime</title>

<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Untitled-1.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
exportRoot = new lib.Untitled1();

stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(2);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background-color:#ffffff">      </canvas>
```

Comment: paste your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Flash? You seem to be using [CreateJS](http://createjs.com/)... And where is this GIF you speak of?

Comment: Do I need to upload the file on any server, as I'm not getting any output in spite of specifying the source of Untitles-1.js in jsfiddle

Comment: I made it in Flash and exported it into HTML using CreateJS @MMM